# Spring Web Mvc with fragments

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, web-fragment

Is there any way to configure the Spring MVC dispatcher servlet in web-fragment.xml file, putting all its listeners and servlet mappings in same fragment.xml file  and putting the dispatcher-servlet.xml under that fragment project itself;like  under META-INF folder?

Comment: Probably, but why do you want to? The trend is toward more modularity rather than glopping everything together into a monolith.

Comment: I want to make a plug and play module using the Web 3.0 Fragments. Configuring the same  can be used in multiple application.